# Tuning with New Relic

Tags: caching, performance, debugging

So I've finally delved into tuning up my aging Drupal 6 site using NewRelic and like most I'm amazed at what their product has to offer. Very useful for honing in on problem areas. However, being new to this I'm not fully sure what the correct actions are to fix my particular problem.

According to NR my biggest issue right now is the _revisioning_view (Revisioning Module) function. Digging through the trace reveals A LOT (1218) of calls to the url_alias table (which currently has 75,000+ records in it) I've read a few things suggesting running memcache or some form of Path Caching. 1218 Calls to url_alias certainly seems like a lot but before I go down the road of installing more modules I'd like to get a better grasp of what's going on here. Does anything jump out to anyone?

My other big item seems to be the time it takes to Insert and Update the cache_content table. See the attached screenshots from NR and let me know where you think I should go first.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've found their tips and tricks webinar to be really helpful https://newrelic.com/resources/webinars/#tips_tricks

Comment: I see similar issues. If you look at the _revisioning_view function (http://drupalcode.org/project/revisioning.git/blob/HEAD:/revisioning.module#l972), it is essentially a pass-through for node_load() with a specific vid.

Answer (score 0):

For the url_alias issue, I'd strongly recommend moving over to [Pressflow](http://pressflow.org/) which provides the path_alias_cache module along with support for it.

> Pressflow is a distribution of Drupal with integrated performance,
>   scalability, availability, and testing enhancements.

I'd also recommend installing [DB Tuner](https://drupal.org/project/dbtuner) on your site to catch any missing indexes.